# CSS3 - HTML Navlist background issue

Tags: html, css, background

I'm currently in my last year of high school and I need to make a basic website.
I've hit a wall with creating my drop-down navlist though.
It works very well, but I have no idea how to make it so that if you scroll over one of the subitems, the background of the hovered-over item covers the whole item.

That sentence was pretty weird, I'm quite new to this.

I've used this jsfiddle thing to sketch the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/5EbSv/5/ .

On the second list item, you can see that the first two list items do not have a fully covered background on hover.

Check out the jsfiddle link for the best example of my problem.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="navlist">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Making an example</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
#menu a{
   color: #0070A2;
}

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

#menu {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}

#menu li {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #292A2C;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #292A2C;
    color: white;
}

#menu li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: grey;
}
```

Thanks for checking it out

Comment: see your updated code http://jsfiddle.net/yasinallana/5EbSv/6/ , update:added a class `.sub` to the problem li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the left float for sub menus list items, e.g.

```
#menu li li {float:none;}
```